How would one calculate the transconductance of the FETs in this circuit?

I was given formulas to find the transconductance (gm) of the FETs using IDSS, VP and VGS, however, none of the ways I tried them leads to the correct answer (given as 2,55mS).

The two formulas you show are correct. But you can't compute \$g_m\$ without knowing \$V_{\text{GS}}\$. And you need the DC operating point to tell you that value.
That means you must work out the DC quiescent operating point for each stage.
In your circuit, you can tentatively consider the gate current as zero. (This assumption is justified by the fact that you aren't given the information that would be needed to compute its actual value.)
So the voltage drop across the \$3.3\:\text{M}\Omega\$ resistor can be treated as \$0\:\text{V}\$ and therefore the gate voltage is \$V_\text{G}=0\:\text{V}\$. From this, you can work out that \$V_\text{GS}=V_\text{G}-V_\text{S}=0\:\text{V}-I_\text{D}\cdot 680\:\Omega\$. So \$I_\text{D}=\frac{-V_\text{GS}}{680\:\Omega}\$.
Recall that \$I_\text{D}=I_\text{DSS}\left(1-\frac{V_\text{GS}}{V_P}\right)^2\$. Substituting, find:  \$10\:\text{mA}\left(1-\frac{V_\text{GS}}{-4\:\text{V}}\right)^2=\frac{-V_\text{GS}}{680\:\Omega}\$. Solve that for \$V_\text{GS}\$.
solve( Eq( 10e-3*(1-vgs/-4)**2, -vgs/680 ), vgs )
[-8.46217412794563, -1.89076704852496]

Obviously, the larger magnitude is wrong. (You should be able to quickly see why.)
Select \$V_\text{GS}\approx -1.89\:\text{V}\$.
Now use your equations:
(2*10e-3/abs(-4))*(1-(-1.89)/(-4))
0.00263750000000000

\$g_m\approx 2.64\:\text{mS}\$. That's pretty close to the value you say is the correct answer.
Let's look at your equations, though. Just as a double-check. The definition of \$g_m\$ is \$g_m=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\, V_\text{GS} }I_\text{D}\$:
diff(idss*(1-vgs/vp)**2,vgs)
-2*idss*(-vgs/vp + 1)/vp

This result validates your equations (recalling that \$V_P\$ is negative, so when using \$\vert V_P\vert\$ the -2 must become +2.)
Recall: I computed \$g_m\approx 2.64\:\text{mS}\$. (With JFETs that's more digits than can be justified.)
The stated answer was \$g_m\approx 2.55\:\text{mS}\$.
I'd consider that close enough.

Gate current is also easily concluded as the gate is pulled to the lowest voltage in the circuit, whereas S and D are same or higher voltage.

@TimWilliams I'm not seeing how it can be concluded from the direct information supplied in the problem. Would you please educate me, given that it is easily concluded? I'm feeling a bit like an idiot, for now. (But I'll happily test out the idea in simulation to learn more.)

At the most basic, a JFET is a complicated diode. D and S are joined by conductive material (channel), and N-channel means G is the P-type joined to it. Hence the symbol's arrow into the channel, indicating a P-N junction.  Indeed, JFETs with D+S tied are regularly used as picoampere diodes. The voltage between D and S, or the degree of channel pinchoff, doesn't change this analysis -- or at worst, we can treat G-D and G-S as independent diodes. Cheers!

@TimWilliams I know. But, and this is critical because of the 3.3 MOhm resistor present, how do you quantitatively compute Ig directly from the information provided in the problem. I'm not seeing the computation without more information.

Since the junction is reverse biased, Ig is, at most, leakage.

@TimWilliams Agreed. But that's not a quantitative value. And the leakage isn't stated in the problem. Not so far as I can see. It can make a difference because of the magnitude of the 3.3 MOhm resistor. So... it may matter. But the information must be in the problem set. It cannot be assumed, other than zero, without more detail presented there. Which brings us full circle back to the statement I made in the answer. There's nothing I can tell the questioner to confirm any assumption I might choose to make towards adjusting the resulting $g_m$.

Well that's what I mean. Even in most practical applications (and that's pretty specific, with JFETs mostly a specialty item these days), Ig can be ignored for biasing purposes. The textbook likely indicates as much.

@TimWilliams Okay. So we are of similar mind. I really do enjoy the discussion -- don't get me wrong about that. But I wanted to make sure we were on the same page. Looks like we are. So I think I agree with your writing, with the notation that it's not possible to actually compute the value for Ig * 3.3 MOhm in this case. It may be important for slight adjustments to $g_m$. But there isn't enough information in the problem and, I think, the author of the problem wanted the assumption to be taken that Ig=0 in this case. Despite that I get a slightly different value. So I'm open to error.

Yeah, not sure about the exact numerical value; also even if there were Ig given, it would only make gm higher. Perhaps there is other background information given in the textbook, but the formulas you used should be pretty standard.

Thank you for the answer, it is so much better than what my teacher later explained. He only taught us to plug in a random value for ID into the formula VGS=-ID/RS, which would become a point in the graph to draw a straight line from the origin to, presumably the DC load line. Then the intersection between that line and the FET's curve would be the Q-point, and the value of VGS at Q-point would be the one to use in the formula for gm.
